# Setting the property "files" in Eslint Config throws an error with Eslint VSCode Extension

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint, vscode-extensions, eslintrc

When I try to set the property "files" in the ESLint Config file ".eslintrc.cjs" I get the following error from the EsLint VsCode Extension:

> ESLint: ESLint configuration in client.eslintrc.cjs is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "files". . Please see the 'ESLint' output channel for details.

Every time I ran npm run lint (I include this script in my package.json file `"lint": "eslint ./**",`), ESlint not only look for errors in .jsx files but also in files like .svg, .png, etc. So, I am trying to add the following property `files: ['src/**/*.jsx'],` to my ESLint Config File to avoid checking the files outside the src directory and the files that are not .jsx.

This is my .eslintrc.cjs file:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'plugin:react/recommended',
  ],
  overrides: [
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  plugins: [
    'react',
  ],
  files: ['src/**/*.jsx'],
  rules: {
    'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
    'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
    'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': ['error', { devDependencies: true }],
    'no-use-before-define': ['error', { functions: false }],
    'no-param-reassign': ['error', { props: false }],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `overrides` to include `files`, e.g.,

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb/hooks', 'plugin:react/recommended'],
  overrides: [
    {
      plugins: ['react'],
      files: ['src/**/*.jsx'],
      rules: {
        'react/jsx-uses-react': 'off',
        'react/react-in-jsx-scope': 'off',
        'import/no-extraneous-dependencies': [
          'error',
          { devDependencies: true },
        ],
        'no-use-before-define': ['error', { functions: false }],
        'no-param-reassign': ['error', { props: false }],
      },
    },
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 'latest',
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
}
```

See documentation here https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files#how-do-overrides-work.

Comment: Thanks, Sam! it worked perfectly! Do I need to include the rules inside overrides as well?

Comment: It depends on your use cases. Those rules in `overrides` would be applied only to `files` you defined alongside, if you set `rules` in the top level, i.e., alongside `env` and the like, ESLint would apply the rules to the default matched files, like `*.js`.